# Should these identical questions with identical answers be merged?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447728/formsauthentication-loginurl) (19 upvotes on the question, 29 on the accepted answer) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073445/mvc-forms-loginurl-is-incorrect) (22 upvotes on the question, 44 on the accepted answer).

Both are practically identical, and answered by the same person (within one month of each other), with the same content (a small `web.config` snippet).

I voted on each to close as the duplicate of the other (is that the right action?), but given the non-trivial scores, I wonder if they should be merged instead?

Update: As per the Meta Effect (TM), the first (lower-scored according to my numbers) answer is now closed as a dupe of the second one.

Comment: If the answers are literally the same, I don't see the need of keeping both of them..

Comment: These are not worth merging because the answers are exactly the same; merging only applies if there is something to gain for future visitors (i.e. seeing the great answers from the dupe on the canonical instead).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merging is a tool to move great answers from a dupe to a canonical post.

We only use this if

1. the questions are essentially the same, there is nothing lost in deleting just the question post.
2. the answers are great, apply to the canonical too, and are *not already present*.

With merging, the canonical post is enriched with more quality answers.

The post you found has no such great answers. There is only one upvoted answer that contains the exact same information as the top answer on the canonical. The answer on the canonical also contains additional information missing on the dupe. Moving that answer won't add anything to the canonical.

Comment: Since these questions and answers are duplicates, and since SO tends to frown on duplicated questions/answers, what (if anything) is the right course of action to take here?

Comment: @ashes999: SO does not frown on duplicate questions. Although we close such questions, they have value by acting as *sign posts* to the canonical, they provide novel keywords for a search engine to match on. As long as the answers are not simple copy-and-paste jobs but are tailored to the question, we generally don't frown upon answers to such questions either, not much anyway. Nothing needs to be done here.

Answer (score 14):

I found [a Stack Overflow blog post from 2009](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/) that had pretty much the same question.

This was stated as a guideline by Jeff Atwood on *Handling Duplicate Questions* (emphasis added on *merge*):

> **Accidental duplicates.** These questions aren't copy and paste, but they cover the exact same ground as an earlier Stack Overflow question. The overlap is not ambiguous; the question uses the same words and asks the same fundamental question, with no variation at all. This is a failing on several levels; of the asker to do proper diligence before asking, of our internal ask page title search, and possibly of Google search as well. We rely on Stack Overflow users to link these questions together by closing them as "exact duplicate" and posting the URL (as a comment, or edit) to the question this is a duplicate of. These sometimes have multiple good answers attached to each question. We will use our new moderator question **merge** function to **merge** them together without losing any answers or comments.
>
> [...] if we determine two questions are accidental duplicates, we can **merge** them together without losing anything except the text of one of the questions; all comments and answers are preserved.

Following that post, I would go with a merge of the questions.

Comment: If that's the case (this answer is currently +3), how do I attract the attention of a moderator or person of sufficient power to merge?

Comment: @ashes999 probably a custom flag on either of the questions and a link to this meta post

Comment: No, there is nothing to merge here.